# Object is possibly 'undefined' Reactjs

Tags: javascript, typescript

this question solution is already available in stackoverflow but, i am still confuse,i have use same as they answer still go this error please help me to get out of this error
thank you
my list of object is

```
 const typeValue = [
        {name: "Subscription", value: "subscription", rank: 2},
        {name: "Single", value: "single", rank: 3},
        {name: "Trial", value: "trial", rank: 0},
        {name: "Unlimited", value: "unlimited", rank: 1000},
        {name: "Promo", value: "promo", rank: 1},
        {name: "Test", value: "test", rank: 0},
        {name: "Brand", value: "brand", rank: 3}
    ]
```

any i want to find rank number

```
  rank: typeValue.find(x => x.value === snapshot.data().type).rank
```

Comment: Can you provide the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

```
typeValue.find(x => x.value === snapshot.data().type)
```

You're trying to find an element in `typeValue` that satisfies `x.value === snapshot.data().type`, but `snapshot.data().type` could be anything so TypeScript is warning that `typeValue.find(x => x.value === snapshot.data().type)` may return `undefined`.

If you want to tell TypeScript that `x.value === snapshot.data().type` will definitely match one of the elements, you can use `!`:

```
rank: typeValue.find(x => x.value === snapshot.data().type)!.rank
```

You can also use `?` if `rank` can be `undefined`:

```
rank: typeValue.find(x => x.value === snapshot.data().type)?.rank
```

Answer (score 0):

`find` will return `undefined` if it can't find a match, and then it is illegal to call `.rank`. To solve, use `?.rank` instead:

```
rank: typeValue.find(x => x.value === snapshot.data().type)?.rank
```

If the problem persists, then you may have to do the same for `.type`:

```
rank: typeValue.find(x => x.value === snapshot.data()?.type)?.rank
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Declare types for you `typeValue` array variable :-

```
const typeValue: { name: string; value: string; rank: number }[] = [
  { name: "Subscription", value: "subscription", rank: 2 },
  { name: "Single", value: "single", rank: 3 },
  { name: "Trial", value: "trial", rank: 0 },
  { name: "Unlimited", value: "unlimited", rank: 1000 },
  { name: "Promo", value: "promo", rank: 1 },
  { name: "Test", value: "test", rank: 0 },
  { name: "Brand", value: "brand", rank: 3 },
];
```

##### Also add types for `snapshot.data().type`, if you didn't declared it already!